# Add fullPage.js to Foundation

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation, fullpage.js

Im interested can I add [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) to [Zurb's Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)? If so does anyone knows a good tutorial on this topic? 
I need to create a page with static background image, with scrollable sections using fullPage.js

Note: I've tried to combine them but, with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foundation is just a front-end framework such as BootStrap, you shouldn't have any problem to implement the jQuery plugin on your site.

You just have to create the needed structure and include the needed files as specified in the  [fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs).

You can also take a look at the [living examples](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) source code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a conflict between foundation's and ajax.googleapis.com jquery needed by fullPage.js. As soon as I removed from my index.html the following line ...

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
```

... fullPage.js started working.

Don't know how this will affect my Foundation, but for now I have grid and topbar working.